# Neuralink in depression treatment

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request, depression, brain-computer-interface

In [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/elon-musks-neuralink-everything-you-need-to-know-a19c35708f9a) article there is a statement that

> [Neuralink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuralink) can help people with Parkinson’s disease, epilepsy, and
>   depression by promptly sending electric pulses into the areas
>   responsible for their specific symptoms.

Could you refer me to the detailed information about depression treatment via
Neuralink?

Comment: Right now, I don't think there is any clinical data released (or even existing?) with the Neuralink system. Neuralink is a newcomer to the field. It might be better to update your question to ask about DBS and depression, or more generally, brain stimulation and depression.

Comment: Example: https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=depression&term=DBS vs https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=neuralink

Comment: @BryanKrause If the mechanism will be the same or similar as Neuralink it may be the answer. I'm interested especially about the mechanism, if it is somewhere described.

Comment: @BryanKrause I agree with xralf. That would provide a suitable answer. As to the specific system, pointing out there are no studies can be part of that answer. If studies ever show up, a new answer can be posted.